# Properly sharing using open graph for asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to utilize the sharing open graph mark up with my asp .net mvc website. I've added the meta tags but when shared, it still gives a generic version of my website, instead of pulling the info from the meta tags.

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://bandwagonbible.com/LifeHacks/LifeLessions" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="The 5 Essential Life Lessons They Don’t Teach in School" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="Just graduated and not sure that you learnt enough in class? These 5 secret lessons will help make your life a whole lot easier." />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://bandwagonbible.com/Stories/LifeHacks/LifeLessons/Image1.jpg" />I
```

I used [Facebook Developers - Object](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) to try to debug but it says the the meta tags are in the body for some reason. May I ask how do I properly use open graph with asp .net mvc I'm thinking maybe because it's in the header of the body?

error message `Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's telling you they're in the body, it's probably because they are. You're going to need to get them in the `<head>` section.

Without knowing *how* you're outputting the tags, it's likely you're just emitting them directly within your view. You may want to leverage a section so you can put them in the proper place. e.g.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <!-- ... -->
  @RenderSection("OpenGraph", required: false)
</head>
<body>
  @Html.RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

**MyView.cshtml**

```
@model WhateverViewModel
@section OpenGraph {
  <meta property="og:..." content="...">
}
@* Rest of view *@
```

Comment: I definitely think this is on the right track! I'm just starting asp .net mvc, may I ask how do I fix RenderSection, it's unrecognizable. I only see RenderAction and RenderPartial

Comment: NVM! It's actually @RenderSection THANKS!

Comment: @Master: Yes, oops. Just plain `@RenderSection`. Probably same with `@RenderBody`. ;-)